# Multidimensional dataframe scatterplot with R ggvis package

Tags: r, legend, ggvis

I want to plot a scatter plot combining multiple columns of my data frame `df`. The data frame looks like this:

```
             x            y         a      b      c          d     e  f
1 1.882665e-09 1.324425e-09 0.7034844    160      g       Loc1  0.25 30
2 7.173770e-09 4.830280e-09 0.6733253    160      g       Loc2  0.25 30
```

The code I have written allows me to plot df$x vs df$y introducing the complementary variable f for the color of the points (I have 3 levels of f).

Here is the code (with some extra lines for log axis):

```
data %>% ggvis(~x, ~y) %>%
+     layer_points(fill = ~factor(f)) %>%
+     scale_numeric("x", trans = "log", expand=0) %>%
+     scale_numeric("y", trans = "log", expand=0)
```

and here is the plot I get:
[image: My scatterplot]

Is it possible to insert one more parameter (like shape) and using as factor another column of the df (for example the column b)? If yes, how to set in a proper way the legend?

## ----------------------------------------------------------

Some, advances in the question.

I managed to plot what I wanted but still the legend is not clear to me.

Here is the new code:

```
data %>% ggvis(~x, ~y) %>%
+     layer_points(fill = ~factor(f), shape = ~factor(b)) %>%
+     scale_numeric("x", trans = "log", expand=0) %>%
+     scale_numeric("y", trans = "log", expand=0) %>%
+     add_axis("x", title = "blabla1") %>%
+     add_axis("y", title = "blabla2") %>%
+     add_legend(c("fill", "shape"))
```

and here is the new graphic:

[image: plot2]

Comment: I see `shape`, `stroke` and `size` arguments for `layer_points` that should map to any variable just as like you did with `fill`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal demo on `mtcars`:

```
library(ggvis)
mtcars %>%
  ggvis(~mpg, ~wt) %>%
  layer_points(fill = ~factor(cyl), shape = ~factor(cyl), 
               stroke = ~factor(cyl), size = ~factor(cyl)) %>%
  scale_nominal("size", range = c(10, 50)) %>% 
  hide_legend("size")
```

[image]

Note that `size` needs some special handling, not sure why though (e.g. `ggplot` knows how to pick the scale automatically, maybe it's development-related?). I had to hide the legend because of that, but the point size works anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is that in your example you have different colors for different shapes. What I want to achieve is not just an esthetic variation but a quantitative one. In my graphic, based on the information of a column in the date frame I should have different shapes, each of one being of a different color following the indication given in a column of the data frame.

Comment: In fact at the end, if for example I have 7 levels in a column of the data frame, i would like to have, for each shape, 7 different colors

Comment: Simply map shape and colour to different variables? In my demo I mapped everything to `cyl` for simplicity.